# How can we handle updateOrCreate method laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel and I want to return message when it what update and say it was update 
but when it was create nothing happen

here is my code

```
  $shop =  UserPurchase::find($user_purchase_id)->shop;
    $shopOwner =  $shop->user;
    $product =  Product::find($product_id);
    $downloadLinkRequest = ProductDownloadStatus::updateOrCreate(
      ['product_id' => $product_id, 'user_purchase_id' => $user_purchase_id, 'shop_id' => $shop->id]);

      toastr()->success('درخواست شما با موفقیت ارسال شد و پس از بررسی توسط مدیر فروشگاه لینک جدید در همین صفحه قابل دسترسی میباشد', 'انجام شد');
      return redirect()->back();
```

how can I know when it is update and when it is create

Comment: Use update for update and create for create maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wasChanged` function to see what happened.

Something like:

```
if($downloadLinkRequest-> wasChanged()){
//Show updated message
}
```

And as a default fallback you can have the created message. You don't need an `else` for that.